# C++: accessing private members of the class

Tags: c++, private

Still getting my head around C++ as I'm new to it, but I'm trying to extend some existing code I've got that is expecting me to make use of the `std::vector`.

The following is declared in the header (shortened for simplicity):

```
class WindowManager
{
     private:
        std::vector<Item*>     m_itemlist;
}
```

My problem is how I'm meant to access this from the .cpp? I'd like to use it to have an array of `Item` type but I don't understand how to actually get to the point where I can add a newly instantiated `Item`, let's say `button`, to the array?

A bit of a rudimentary question but I've not had much luck with tutorials that cover std::vector.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific as to what difficulties you suffer from.

Comment: Your `WindowManager` class needs functions that interact with the vector.  It is like any other private member variable.

Comment: So the question isn't about `vector` in the first place but on "how to alter private data members"?

Comment: I think you have oversimplified the problem. As written, the `WindowManager` `class` is completely useless because its `m_itemlist` member is unaccessible. It can only be accessed from member functions because it is `private` but there is no member function declared.

Comment: Side note: why are you using `std::vector<Item*>` instead of `std::vector<Item>`? Just making sure you're not doing anything unnecessary - very often vector of pointers is not needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If possible avoid using vector of pointers to Item. Use vector of Item directly.

```
class WindowManager
{
    void addItem(Item const& item) { m_itemlist.push_back(item); }

private:
    std::vector<Item> m_itemlist;
};

int main()
{
    WindowManager wm;
    Item i;
    wm.addItem(i);
}
```

Comment: Given that the OP asks about adding a `button` to the `vector`, I assume it needs to be polymorphic. But in general, your advice is good.

Comment: `Item` may be the base of a polymorphic hierarchy...

Comment: @5gon12eder - your probably right. OP is probably looking for vector of pointers. Still, OP writes `I'd like to use it to have an array of Item type`... well, a bit unclear. Anyway, the question is on hold now so I'll just leave it as is.

Comment: @Dennis - Probably correct. See comment above as well.

Answer (score 3):

To add an item you could use a member function like this:

```
class WindowManager
{
private:
    std::vector<Item *> m_itemlist;
public:
    void addItem(Item *newItem);
}
```

in window_manager.cpp:

```
void WindowManager::addItem(Item *newItem)
{
    m_itemlist.push_back(newItem);
}
```

see [`std::vector::push_back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)